# Line-height with padding

Tags: javascript, css

**The solution of Roko C. Buljan doesn't work in i.e.**

I want to get this design (assuming the background is unique color with transparent):

[image]

I can do it with `box-decoration-break` property.

Unfortunately, the property `box-decoration-break` is not supported in IE.

I saw something similar to my design, but I can't set line-height without destroying the design.

In addition, when I change the font-size, the design is destroyed.

https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

This is my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9472J/37/

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you use line-height in an inner element of your DOM? This wouldn't affect the attributes of the parent elements at all. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div{width:130px; margin-left:20px}

span.padded{
  font:       18px/32px sans-serif;            /* Font size and line-height spacing */
  box-shadow: 8px 0 0 0 #555, -8px 0 0 0 #555; /* 8px horiz. "padding" */
  padding:    4px 0;                           /* 4px vertical padding */
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
          box-decoration-break: clone;
  color:      #fff;
  background: #555;
/*display:    inline; /* Uncomment if you use block-level element */
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    span.padded{         /* 0.5px spread fixes blurry box shadow in FF */
        box-shadow: 8px 0 0 0.5px #555, -8px 0 0 0.5px #555; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="padded">Lorem ipsum this is some padded text with background</span>
</div>
```

### FF half-pixel box-shadow precision issue fixed

Firefox has this issue that does not know how to properly sharp `box-shadow`.
`0px spread-radius` **blur issue**:

[image]

So a box-shadow spread-radius has to be expressed using (unbelievably) **half-pixel precision** (for -moz- only!):

`0.5px spread-radius` **blur fix**:

[image]

Since `using 0.5px` spread-radius on box shadow creates respectively the same issue in Webkit, let's target only Mozilla using

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    span.padded{
        box-shadow: 8px 0 0 0.5px #555, -8px 0 0 0.5px #555;
    }
}
```

### IE, Edge - blured `box-shadow` half-pixel issue

There's no hope (at the time of writing) for [**IE11** and **Edge** (Blur issue still present)](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810756/ie-11-gap-between-element-background-and-its-box-shadow)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break

Comment: Amazing! I thought that I can't achieve it without using javascript..
I am testing it.. thank you..

Comment: @AlonShmiel add `box-decoration-break:clone;`

Comment: sorry but there is a light gray line in the left of the text.. https://jsfiddle.net/9472J/44/

You can see it in Firefox and IE..

Comment: @AlonShmiel That's a FF issue with  box shadows not being sharp... trying to figure out a fix...

Comment: @AlonShmiel done. Finally. Using half values `4.5px` box-shadow offset- see edit

Comment: Thank you again.. I'm very very sorry, but now internet explorer is the last one that doesn't work (it works in chrome, firefox, safari).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109546/discussion-between-alon-shmiel-and-roko-c-buljan).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the closest you can get using just CSS rules that are supported by all the browsers.

This is my attempt:

```css
section {
  max-width:400px;
  padding:50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800');
  background-size:cover;
  height:100vh;
}

section > h1 {
  display:inline;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7), -10px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  color:#fff;
  padding:4px 0;
  line-height:200%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight:100;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolore, temporibus consequatur.
  </h1>  
</section>
```

**Additional Note:**

- In order to achieve the transparent background I'm using `rgba` instead of `rgb` in both background and box-shadow. At the moment the opacity is set to 70% (.7 in rgba) but you can set it to taste.

Comment: Thank you, but you missed the padding-left and padding-right in every line.

Comment: @AlonShmiel I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works now

Answer (score 1):

`box-shadow` do the trick:

HTML:

```
<section>
  <span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolore, temporibus consequatur.
  </span>  
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
  max-width:400px;
  padding:50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/800');
  background-size:cover;
  height:100vh;
}

span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.8;
  padding: 3px 0 6px 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .6), -10px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Now it work also on Firefox. Because the default on FF is `box-decoration-break: split;`, `box-decoration-break: clone;` must be set.

Comment: Yep, see it also too late.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't look good in IE,, There is a light line in the left and in the right of the text.